# How to get three divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have this project I'm working on where I have to make a simple webpage where there are three divs of equal size side by side. Here's a [project description](https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course4/blob/master/assignments/assignment2/Assignment-2.md).

I've tried a lot of different ways to make it responsive, by making the first and second divs float left and making the third div float right and setting width to 30%.

I've also tried setting their display to inline-block and setting the width however the layout might work but when I change the viewport width, it changes the layout like the last div wraps below the others. I'm not sure why this happens, does anyone have any ideas?

Code:

```css
body{
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
div{
    background-color: rgb(183, 183, 183);
    font-size:30px;
    border:dotted;
}
/* Large Devices*/
@media(min-width:992px){
    .Parent{
        width: 30%;
        display:inline-block;
        height:300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin:2.5%;
    }
    div.child_tag{
        padding:2.5%;
        float:right;
        width:30%;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:30px;
    }
    #chicken
    {
        background-color: #e99191;
    }
    #beef{
        background-color:#dfb2d9;
    }
    #sushi{
        background-color:#aadae6;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>
        Module 2 Solution
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our Menu</h1>
    <div class = "col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 Parent" id = "chicken_p">
        <div id = "chicken" class="child_tag">Chicken</div>
        <p>Lssdfjsdf lsjfljsd jsdjsdl ljljlsdlj lsdjflsj lsjdljsd</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 Parent" id = "beef_p">
        <div id = "beef" class="child_tag">Beef</div>
        <p>Lssdfjsdf lsjfljsd jsdjsdl ljljlsdlj lsdjflsj lsjdljsd</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 Parent" id = "sushi_p">
        <div id = "sushi" class="child_tag">Sushi</div>
        <p>Lssdfjsdf lsjfljsd jsdjsdl ljljlsdlj lsdjflsj lsjdljsd</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Tips: 1) A web developer should never dump raw URLs into a page, even if it's a question on SO. 2) Floats are an old, hacky way to do layout. Don't use them for that. 3) There are scores of questions on SO dealing with this exact problem. Have you searched?

Comment: The tool for dealing with this, since it achieved widespread support in 2013, is Flexbox.

Comment: And 4)... you appear to be using the Bootstrap library, _which does all this for you_. Please tag your version.

Comment: Never mind. From the project guide: _You are NOT allowed to use any CSS (or Javascript) framework for this assignment, including Twitter Bootstrap CSS Framework._

Comment: 5) Be sure you're following tutorials and guides from this decade. The internet is very old, and there are many obsolete strategies laying around for the unsuspecting newbie. One of the best resources is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US. I also like https://css-tricks.com, especially for its flexbox guide.